# Не срабатывает mouseup в drag and drop

Tags: javascript

```
      'use strict';

   var sliderElem = document.querySelector('.horizontal-slider__slider-body');
   var thumbElem = document.querySelector('.horizontal-slider__slider-drag-
   btn');
   var manIcons = document.querySelectorAll('.horizontal-slider_man-icon-
    block');

    thumbElem.onmousedown = function(e) {
      var thumbCoords = getCoords(thumbElem);
      var shiftX = e.pageX - thumbCoords.left;      

      var sliderCoords = getCoords(sliderElem);
      var sliderThumbLeftPos = thumbElem.style.left;      

      var mousemoveEvent = document.addEventListener("mousemove", slider());

      thumbElem.onmouseup = function () {
        mousemoveEvent = null;          
        thumbElem.onmouseup = null;;
      };      

      function slider(e) {
            var event = e;
            var xDirection = "";
            var oldX = 0;
            function move (event) {             
        if (oldX < event.pageX) {
        xDirection = 1; //right
        } else {
            xDirection = 2; //left
        }

        //  вычесть координату родителя, т.к. position: relative
        var newLeft = event.pageX - shiftX - sliderCoords.left;        
        // курсор ушёл вне слайдера
        if (newLeft < 0) {
          newLeft = 0;
        }
        var rightEdge = sliderElem.offsetWidth;
        if (newLeft > rightEdge) {
          newLeft = rightEdge;
        }

        thumbElem.style.left = newLeft + 'px';

        var sliderLeftPositionPersentage = Math.round(newLeft * 100 / 
    sliderElem.offsetWidth);
        var reverseSliderLeftPositionPersentage = (sliderLeftPositionPersentage 
    - 100) * -1;
        thumbElem.innerHTML =  newLeft;
        var manIconForVisibility = Math.floor(sliderLeftPositionPersentage / 
    10);

        if (xDirection == 1 && manIconForVisibility > 0 ) {
            manIcons[manIconForVisibility-1].style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        if (xDirection == 2 && manIconForVisibility > 0 ) {
            manIcons[manIconForVisibility-1].style.visibility = "";
        }

          oldX = event.pageX;
          return oldX;
        }

        return move;
            }

      return false; // disable selection start (cursor change)
    };

    thumbElem.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
    };

    function getCoords(elem) {
      var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

      return {
        top: box.top + pageYOffset,
        left: box.left + pageXOffset
      };

    }
```

Пытаюсь сделать ползунок drag and drop, mouseup срабатывает, но мышка продолжает двигать ползунок.

Answer (score 0):

Переменная `mousemoveEvent` бесполезна, т.к. `addEventListener` не имеет возвращаемого значения.

Далее, вместо:

```
mousemoveEvent = null;
```

нужно использовать `removeEventListener`.

Comment: про переменную понял, removeEventListener пробовал, если использовать функцию без замыкания, работает, а с замыканием нет